# my html page footer doesn't show

Tags: html, css

i have a login page that must have a footer but i don't know why my footer doesn't show, here is my html and css file, please someone tell what is wrong?

**HTML :**

```
    <body>

    <!-- Begin Page Content -->

    <div id="container">

        <form  method="POST" id="login">

        <label for="name">تلفن همراه :</label>

        <input type="tel" required="" title="لطفا شماره همراه خود را به صورت صحیح وارد نمایید" x-moz-errormessage="لط
        فا شماره همراه خود را به صورت صحیح وارد نمایید" name="phone" id="phone">

        <label for="username">رمز عبور :</label>

        <input  type="password" required="" id="password" title="رمز عبور را وارد کنید" x-moz-errormessage="رمز عبور را وارد کنید" name="password">

        <div id="lower">

        <input type="checkbox"><label class="check" for="checkbox">مرا بخاطر بسپار</label>


        <input type="submit" value="ورود"  ><br />
        <a style=" float: right; clear:both; margin-right: 10px;margin-bottom:10px;  text-decoration: blink;" href="register.php">ثبتنام نکرده ام</a>
        </div>

        </form>

    </div>
    <div class="footer">
            <div>
                    <a href="http://hameja123.ir">همه جا 123</a>
            </div>
                    کلیه حقوق این سایت محفوظ بوده و متعلق به
                    <a href="http://hameja123.ir">همه جا 123</a>
                    می‌باشد.
            <div style="direction:ltr; color: #ffffff;">hameja123.ir - Copyright       ©  2013 - All rights reserved by Reza Tanzifi.</div>

        </div><!--end footer-->

    <!-- End Page Content -->
</body>
```

**CSS :**

```
@import url(animate.css);

    /* Selections */

    ::selection {
        color: #fff;
        text-shadow: none;
        background: #444;
    }

    ::-moz-selection {
        color: #fff;
        text-shadow: none;
        background: #444;
    }

    /* Basics */

    html, body {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
        color: #444;
        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
        background-image: url(./images/bg.png);
        background-repeat: repeat;

    }

    #container {
        position: fixed;
        width: 340px;
        height: 280px;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        margin-top: -140px;
        margin-left: -170px;
        background: #fff;
        border-radius: 3px;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
        -webkit-animation-name: bounceIn;
        -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
        -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
        -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
        -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
        -moz-animation-name: bounceIn;
        -moz-animation-fill-mode: both;
        -moz-animation-duration: 1s;
        -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
        -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
        animation-name: bounceIn;
        animation-fill-mode: both;
        animation-duration: 1s;
        animation-iteration-count: 1;
        animation-timing-function: linear;
    }

    form {
        margin: 0 auto;
        margin-top: 20px;
    }

    label {
        color: #555;
        display: inline-block;
        margin-right: 18px;
        padding-top: 10px;
        font-size: 14px;
        direction: rtl;
        float: right;
    }

    p a {
        font-size: 11px;
        color: #aaa;
        float: right;
        margin-top: -13px;
        margin-right: 20px;
        -webkit-transition: all .4s ease;
        -moz-transition: all .4s ease;
        transition: all .4s ease;
    }

    p a:hover {
        color: #555;
    }

    input {
        font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size: 12px;
        outline: none;
    }

    input[type=tel],
    input[type=password] {
        color: #777;
        padding-left: 10px;
        margin: 10px;
        margin-top: 12px;
        margin-left: 18px;
        width: 290px;
        height: 35px;
        border: 1px solid #c7d0d2;
        border-radius: 2px;
        box-shadow: inset 0 1.5px 3px rgba(190, 190, 190, .4), 0 0 0 5px #f5f7f8;
        -webkit-transition: all .4s ease;
        -moz-transition: all .4s ease;
        transition: all .4s ease;
    }

    input[type=tel]:hover,
    input[type=password]:hover {
        border: 1px solid #b6bfc0;
        box-shadow: inset 0 1.5px 3px rgba(190, 190, 190, .7), 0 0 0 5px #f5f7f8;
    }

    input[type=tel]:focus,
    input[type=password]:focus {
        border: 1px solid #a8c9e4;
        box-shadow: inset 0 1.5px 3px rgba(190, 190, 190, .4), 0 0 0 5px #e6f2f9;
    }

    #lower {
        background: #ecf2f5;
        width: 100%;
        height: 69px;
        margin-top: 20px;
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px #fff;
        border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
    }

    input[type=checkbox] {
        margin-top: 10px;
        float: right;
        margin-right: 30px;
    }

    .check {
        margin-left: 3px;
        margin-right: 5px;
        font-size: 11px;
        color: #444;
        text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
        float: right;

    }

    input[type=submit] {
        float: left;
        margin-left: 20px;
        margin-top: 20px;
        width: 80px;
        height: 30px;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #fff;
        background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#acd6ef),to(#6ec2e8));
        background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top left 90deg, #acd6ef 0%, #6ec2e8 100%);
        background-image: linear-gradient(top left 90deg, #acd6ef 0%, #6ec2e8 100%);
        border-radius: 30px;
        border: 1px solid #66add6;
        box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3), inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    input[type=submit]:hover {
        background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#b6e2ff), to(#6ec2e8));
        background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top left 90deg, #b6e2ff 0%, #6ec2e8 100%);
        background-image: linear-gradient(top left 90deg, #b6e2ff 0%, #6ec2e8 100%);
    }

    input[type=submit]:active {
        background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#6ec2e8),   to(#b6e2ff));
        background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top left 90deg, #6ec2e8 0%, #b6e2ff 100%);
        background-image: linear-gradient(top left 90deg, #6ec2e8 0%, #b6e2ff 100%);
    }
    .footer{
        background-color: #555555;
        border-top: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
        clear: both;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        font-size: 12px;
        height: 64px;
        line-height: 19px;
        margin-top: -69px;
        padding-top: 4px;
        position: absolute;
        direction: rtl;
        font-family: tahoma;
        font-size: 13px;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 19px;


    }
    .footer a {
        color: #FFFFFF;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
```

Comment: Updated answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/18308779/1256403. @user2668753

Answer (score 1):

In the CSS for footer

change to

```
position: relative;
top: 600px; /* change according to your needs */
```

[JSFidle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mDzwa/)

Answer (score 0):

```
.footer{
    background-color: #555555;
    border-top: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    clear: both;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 12px;
    height: 64px;
    line-height: 19px;
    margin-top: -69px;
    padding-top: 4px;
    position: absolute;
    direction: rtl;
    font-family: tahoma;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 19px;
    left:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    right:0px;
    z-index:100;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just missed to add positioning attributes to your footer class selector:
http://jsfiddle.net/2PE9b/

```
.footer{
background-color: #555555;
border-top: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
clear: both;
color: #FFFFFF;
font-size: 12px;
height: 64px;
line-height: 19px;
margin-top: -69px;
padding-top: 4px;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
left:0;
right:0;
direction: rtl;
font-family: tahoma;
font-size: 13px;
text-align: center;
line-height: 19px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

as previous answer you are using absolute for footer.. you have to define bottom and width:

```
    /* Stylesheet */


/* Imports */

@import url(animate.css);

/* Selections */

::selection {
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: none;
    background: #444;
}

::-moz-selection {
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: none;
    background: #444;
}

/* Basics */

html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #444;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    background-image: url(./images/bg.png);
    background-repeat: repeat;

}

#container {
    position: fixed;
    width: 340px;
    height: 280px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -140px;
    margin-left: -170px;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
    -webkit-animation-name: bounceIn;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -moz-animation-name: bounceIn;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode: both;
    -moz-animation-duration: 1s;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-name: bounceIn;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
}

form {
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

label {
    color: #555;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 18px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    font-size: 14px;
    direction: rtl;
    float: right;
}

p a {
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #aaa;
    float: right;
    margin-top: -13px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    -webkit-transition: all .4s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .4s ease;
    transition: all .4s ease;
}

p a:hover {
    color: #555;
}

input {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    outline: none;
}

input[type=tel],
input[type=password] {
    color: #777;
    padding-left: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
    margin-top: 12px;
    margin-left: 18px;
    width: 290px;
    height: 35px;
    border: 1px solid #c7d0d2;
    border-radius: 2px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1.5px 3px rgba(190, 190, 190, .4), 0 0 0 5px #f5f7f8;
    -webkit-transition: all .4s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .4s ease;
    transition: all .4s ease;
}

input[type=tel]:hover,
input[type=password]:hover {
    border: 1px solid #b6bfc0;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1.5px 3px rgba(190, 190, 190, .7), 0 0 0 5px #f5f7f8;
}

input[type=tel]:focus,
input[type=password]:focus {
    border: 1px solid #a8c9e4;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1.5px 3px rgba(190, 190, 190, .4), 0 0 0 5px #e6f2f9;
}

#lower {
    background: #ecf2f5;
    width: 100%;
    height: 69px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px #fff;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
    margin-top: 10px;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 30px;
}

.check {
    margin-left: 3px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #444;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
    float: right;

}

input[type=submit] {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    width: 80px;
    height: 30px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #fff;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#acd6ef),to(#6ec2e8));
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top left 90deg, #acd6ef 0%, #6ec2e8 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(top left 90deg, #acd6ef 0%, #6ec2e8 100%);
    border-radius: 30px;
    border: 1px solid #66add6;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3), inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
    cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=submit]:hover {
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#b6e2ff), to(#6ec2e8));
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top left 90deg, #b6e2ff 0%, #6ec2e8 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(top left 90deg, #b6e2ff 0%, #6ec2e8 100%);
}

input[type=submit]:active {
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#6ec2e8),   to(#b6e2ff));
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top left 90deg, #6ec2e8 0%, #b6e2ff 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(top left 90deg, #6ec2e8 0%, #b6e2ff 100%);
}
.footer{
    background-color: #555555;
    border-top: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    clear: both;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 12px;
    height: 64px;
    line-height: 19px;
    margin-top: -69px;
    padding-top: 4px;
    position: absolute;
    direction: rtl;
    font-family: tahoma;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 19px;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;

}
.footer a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make the text in the footer appear by adding

```
<br style="clear:both"; />
```

Above your footer, but the footer is still on the top of the screen.

http://jsfiddle.net/sVxUT/1/

Answer (score 0):

Just remove these styles from `.footer`:

```
margin-top: -69px;
position: absolute;
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/PSEhb/)**
and if you want to your footer sticks to bottom of the page write this code:

```
body:before{
    content:"";
    height:100%;
    float:left;
}
```

**[**Demo*](http://jsfiddle.net/7a3rb/)***

Answer (score 0):

Working:

```
 html, body {
        width: 100%;
        font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
        color: #444;
        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
        background-image: url(./images/bg.png);
        background-repeat: repeat;

    }

.footer{
    background-color: #555555;
    border-top: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    clear: both;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 12px;
    height: 64px;
    line-height: 19px;
    padding-top: 4px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left:0;
    width: 100%;
    direction: rtl;
    font-family: tahoma;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-align: center;



}
```

Remove `height:100%` from html, body and `margin-top: -69px;` from footer class.

Added  `bottom: 0;` `left:0;` `width:100%` to footer class

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/83VKn/show/